# CakePHP 3 How keep value and key fields same in select options?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a array like

```
<?php $words = ['a','b','c'] ?>
```

After try cakephp code

```
<?= $this->Form->select('word', $words) ?>
```

My select box is looking like

```
<select name="word">
    <option value="0">a</option>
    <option value="1">b</option>
    <option value="2">c</option>
</select>
```

How can I get my output like

```
<select name="word">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am inclined to remove the CakePHP label, as this is a very basic PHP only question actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form helper will use the array keys as the `option` element values, so you fix the problem by passing an array where the keys have the values that you desire.

For example use [**`array_combine()`**](https://www.php.net/array_combine) to create a new array using the existing array's values as keys:

```php
$words = array_combine($words, $words);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Select Pickers](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)**